# Indestructible Super Shrimp

Tags: evolution

How are shrimp and other animals able to not be crushed by the 1000x greater pressure at the bottom on the Mariana trench?

Wiki says the trench is home to "large living creatures such as a sole or flounder about 30 cm (1 ft) long, and shrimp"

I understand natural selection, but what features has evolution "selected" that enable soft flesh and bones to not be instantly crushed like our own skulls would be at that depth?

Comment: Should I ever have a band, I'll name it "Indestructible Super Shrimp".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aquatic animals brethe the water around them and this equalizes their body pressure with that of the surrounding environment.

This is how you can still find say a piece of pottery or a watch from a shipwreck... They are filled with water and don't experience the pressure.

Such pressures do affect humans because we breathe air and so we can't adapt to pressures underwater and we need a shell that allows the ship environment to be tolerable for humans beyond a couple of hundred feet or so.

I think the change of pressure would also affect fish or other animals If they dropped in depth too quickly.